# The ternary operator in a one-line function

Tags: julia, ternary-operator

In Julia, I might want to write a function that returns `0` if the input is less than `1`, or returns `2` if the input is greater than or equal to `1`. This is a pretty simple function, and the verbosity of a five-line `if else` construct is probably excessive. So I'm trying to turn it into a one-line function. The best I can come up with is as follows:

```
f(x::Number) = begin (x < 1) && return(0); return(2); end
```

or

```
f(x::Number) = begin x < 1 ? (y=0) : (y=2); return(y); end
```

Are there any simpler ways to define this function?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
julia> f(x::Number) = x < 1 ? 0 : 2
f (generic function with 1 method)

julia> f(0)
0

julia> f(1)
2

julia> f(0.99)
0
```

Comment: Well, that one was really staring me in the face wasn't it :-)    Many thanks

Answer (score 3):

Alternative solution:

```
f(x::Number) = if (x < 1) 0 else 2 end
```

The if-elseif-else syntax in Julia *will return the value of the expression that gets executed*, which imho makes the C-like ternary operator rather superfluous. As in, all of its functionality is encompassed by a more readable alternative.

Looking at your previous attempts, I think it is worth mentioning that unlike in say Python, you rarely need to explicitly use return(). Often you can just return whatever your if-elseif-else blocks return, much like you would in most lisp dialects. Explicit return is like goto or break, something that you use to break control flow in exceptional cases.